# Unix: grep suits of cards

Tags: unix, grep

So I need to grep the collection that is given here:

γ = { h ∈ H | h contains at least 3 cards of every suit} examples:

`Ad7hTc4h8d8sAsKd5c9cQhJdTs ∈ γ` 
`5dKc9cJcTh7sQc3s4sAs7c2cTs ∉ γ`

The suits are `c` `d` `h` `s`.

The file that I needed to use is given here:
http://computergebruik.ugent.be/oefeningenreeks1/kaarten1.txt

Thanks in advance!

** I tried `egrep -c ‘([cdhs]).*\1.*\1 ’ kaarten1.txt` but that command only matches one of the 4 characters 3 times, but I also need to match the other 3 characters 3 times... So I tried another one `egrep -c ‘([c]).*\1.*\1 | [d]).*\1.*\1 | [h]).*\1.*\1 | [s]).*\1.*\1 ’ kaarten1.txt` but that also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Exercices from college that I can't figure out... I have a problem and I need to find a solution, I have tried many grep variations but I can't seem to solve it. So why not ask a question here?

Comment: This is definitely a good place to ask a question. Could you add the different variations of grep you have tried?

Comment: Of course. Here you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use multiple greps, searching for the suits one at a time and chaining the greps together. Each grep will successively cull non-matching hands from the results. In pseudo-code:

```
grep 3-diamonds | grep 3-hearts | grep 3-spades | grep 3-clubs
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to write those individual greps.